# Error deserializing XML using Jackson to generated choice from XSD

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xsd, jackson

I am currently trying to deserialize incoming XML to objects generated from an XSD. Sadly, there seems to be a problem when trying to deserialize to a generated choice element. I have tried quite a few things, and I even just implemented the very basic example as can be seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html). Every time I get the same exception. The implementation is as follows:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String xml =
            "<Foo>    \n" +
            "    <A> 1 </A>\n" +
            "    <B> 2.5 </B>\n" +
            "</Foo>";

    final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    final Foo foo = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Foo.class);
}

public static class Foo {

    @XmlElementRefs({
            @XmlElementRef(name = "A", type = Integer.class),
            @XmlElementRef(name = "B", type = Float.class)
    })
    public List items;
}
```

In my application, instead of the explicit types, every element is given the basic JAXBElement type. The exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "A" (class x.y.z.Application$Foo), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "items"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: x.y.z.Application$Foo["A"])
```

It seems like he is simply looking for a field with given name, trying to set the value to this, which of course does not exist.

I have seen comparable questions here where answers stated you should add a configuration to ignore unknown, which is not what I want. I expect the list to contain two elements in the end, namely the two numbers.

I have also seen an extension called Simplify in order to generate a list field for each choice element. In my use case, I actually would prefer to have the all added to the single list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc for `@XmlElements` you linked to is based around JAXB.  E.g. parsing (unmarshalling) and serializing (marshalling) that XML using JAXB directly:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

    String xml = 
            "<Foo>    \n" + 
            "    <A> 1 </A>\n" +
            "    <B> 2.5 </B>\n" +
            "</Foo>";

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
    Foo foo = (Foo) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(sr);
    System.out.println(foo.items);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    jaxbContext.createMarshaller().marshal(foo, sw);
    System.out.println(sw);
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
public static class Foo {

    @XmlElements({ 
        @XmlElement(name = "A", type = Integer.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "B", type = Float.class) 
    })
    public List items;
}
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2.5]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Foo><A>1</A><B>2.5</B></Foo>
```

There are a couple of tweaks from the example in the question above:

- `@XmlRootElement` is needed to allow the starting `<Foo>` element
- It needs to be `@XmlElement(s)` instead of `@XmlElementRef(s)` for the basic `Integer` and `Float` types

---

You're right that Jackson should also be able to work with those annotations.  To do this you would also need to enable that module: `xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule())`

However that doesn't bring things together too well for this example still.  For example, trying to go both ways again:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws IOException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());

    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.items = Arrays.asList(1, 2.5f);

    String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(foo);
    System.out.println(xml);

    xml = 
            "<Foo>    \n" + 
            "    <A> 1 </A>\n" +
            "    <B> 2.5 </B>\n" + 
            "</Foo>";

    foo = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Foo.class);
}

public static class Foo {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @XmlElements({ 
        @XmlElement(name = "A", type = Integer.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "B", type = Float.class) 
    })
    public List items;
}
```

... returned this ...

```
<Foo><items>1</items><items><B>2.5</B></items></Foo>

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "A" (class so.xmllist.XmlElementsTestBasic$Foo), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "items"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: so.xmllist.XmlElementsTestBasic$Foo["A"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Using JAXB directly also gave the result I needed in my project. Do you have any guess as to why using Jackson even with the registered module does not work?

Comment: The problem with JAXB is that if you use that you're stuck on Java 8 (yes, I find a lot of solutions, no one worked), and Jackson seems to not work even with the JAXB module, as you pointed out. It's a difficult world.

Answer (score 2):

For just deserialization, you could use setter method to instruct XmlMapper:

```
public class Foo {

    public List items;

    public Foo() {
        items = new ArrayList();
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "A")
    public void setA(Integer a) {
        items.add(a);
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "B")
    public void setB(Double b) {
        items.add(b);
    }
}
```

Calling

```
final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
final Foo foo = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Foo.class);
```

Will give:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, although I am auto generating the classes using xjc, and I do not want to manually patch the classes. So unless it is easy configurable, I'd rather not do it like this. But thanks for the answer!