# Serialize XML "choice" element with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xsd, jackson-dataformat-xml

We have an XSD of this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0.0">
    <xs:element name="SomeEndpoint">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="RequestPayload">
                    <!-- snip -->
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ResponsePayload">
                    <!-- snip -->
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="ErrorPayload">
                    <!-- snip -->
                </xs:element>
            <xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Never mind if we like it; it's given. So for instance, for a request, we'd get XML of the form

```xml
<SomeEndpoint>
    <RequestPayload>
        <!-- snip -->
    </RequestPayload>
</SomeEndpoint>
```

For our own sanity, we want to have three POXOs, so to speak:

```java
@JsonTypeName("RequestPayload")
class SomeEndpointRequestPayload {
}

@JsonTypeName("ResponsePayload")
class SomeEndpointResponsePayload {
}

@JsonTypeName("ErrorPayload")
class SomeEndpointErrorPayload {
}
```

So far, so good -- we can, using Jackon 2.11.0 with `jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.2`, serialize the "real" objects just fine. FWIW, we use a mapper configured like so:

```java
public XmlMapper payloadMapper() {
    var xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    return xmlMapper;
}
```

Now we "only" need that wrapping tag, `SomeEndpoint`. Things we've tried:

- **Root Path:** We thought that it might be possible to inject a custom "root path" for a POXO via `@JsonRootName` or `@JacksonXmlRootElement`. We tried passing names like `SomeEndpoint.RequestPayload` or `SomeEndpoint/RequestPayload`; no luck.
- **Wrapper Object:** This seems the most natural solution, but we struggled not getting an additional wrapping tag named after the property. In particular, this variant is not accepted by Jackson:

  ```java
  @JsonRootName(value = "SomeEndpoint")
  class SomeEndpointWrapper {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Object payload;
  }
  ```

  This one still outputs a `<payload>` tag:

  ```java
  @JsonRootName(value = "SomeEndpoint")
  class SomeEndpointWrapper {
     @XmlElements({
       @XmlElement(name="RequestPayload", type=SomeEndpointRequestPayload.class),
       @XmlElement(name="ResponsePayload", type=SomeEndpointResponsePayload.class),
       @XmlElement(name="ErrorPayload", type=SomeEndpointErrorPayload.class)
     })
     Object payload;
  }
  ```

  We've tried too many mixes of annotations to count, or reproduce here, but these two seemed like "should work".

  *Note bene:* We've been using a marker interface instead of `Object` to restrict values to the three types. Since it doesn't seem to make a difference to Jackson, I've left it out for the sake of simplicity.
- **Workaround:** We can have one property per choice option:

  ```java
  @Data
  @JsonRootName(value = "SomeEndpoint")
  class SomeEndpointWrapper {
    @JsonProperty(value = "Request")
    private SomeEndpointRequestPayload request;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Antwort")
    private SomeEndpointResponsePayload successResponse;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Fehlerinformation")
    private SomeEndpointErrorPayload errorResponse;
  }
  ```

  This works, but ... nah, really?

What's a good way to implement an XML `choice` in POXOs without creating spurious wrapping tags?

Comment: have you found a working solution by now?

Comment: @DarioViva Nope, and project moved on. IIRC, we stuck with that workaround.

Comment: if you just need to deserialize you could do something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842885/17133024